# android: many activities share the same onclicklistener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

There are many activities in my application, every activity has a same button,
  I would like to set the button's listener in a public class,and then every activity could use it . May I? And how to do?

for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MessageSend ms=new MessageSend(getApplicationContext(),？？？);

}
```

}

```
public class MessageSend  implements OnClickListener{ 


public MessageSend(Context context,？？？){

this.context=context;       
View mView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_message_send, null);
Button button=  (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Do someting
    }
});
}
```

}
The activity_main layout include the layout_message_send.
 Could i use the way to use the button's listener? if could, the ??? param is ? if not, can you give me a sample?

Comment: yes you can .The question is are they all perform same action on onClick?

Comment: Try adopting any design pattern. In your case I hope you can read on strategy pattern. Create a class that implements View.Onclicklistenern. Add you code in the onClick. Add a constructor passing the ApplicationContext. then in you button click, creat a new Object of you custom listener and pass the context in constructor. Using the passed context write you own code in the custom class onclick m ethod.

Comment: What is the button click going to do? If the task it has to perform is same thing across. Then you could create a simple class, pass the context and button id in parameters(or whatever more params you need ) and call that    method in the onclick () . Does it answer your Question?

Comment: If you have same button and multiple screen, you can modify your code to oneactivity and multiple fragments. It will help for your code resuablility if you adopt to fragment.s

Comment: Why not, just Interface in Java, any class can implements it.

Comment: <Button android:onClick="doStuff" />

    public void doStuff(View view) {}

Comment: May be I don't describe clearly，i edited  it ,would you like to help me?thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First Refer this Question/Answer from this Link..

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110106/what-is-the-proper-way-to-implement-the-onclicklistener-interface-for-many-butto

**Use any of them or Try it other way which is described below.**

If you want to use same method for multiple button from different activities, and you don't want to repeat code.

I prefer to make Common Class For all activities.

**Example**

Create a `class` and `public static` method in that `class`, and use that method for different `Button` from different `Activities`.

```
public class CommonUtils {

    // Common Functions
    public static void yourMethodName(Context contx,Other Params) {
        //Do ur code
    }
}
```

Write this code when you want to use that Function. You can write this on Button's `onClickListener()`;

```
CommonUtils.yourMethodName(Your params);
```

It helps you to do less coding and you have to change only once if you ever want to change anything.

Comment: May be I don't describe clearly，i edited  it ,would you like to help me?thank you very much!